# Why elements in a vector need to be copy constructable?

Tags: c++, vector, auto-ptr

I have this question because I am reading the section for `auto_ptr`. It says `auto_ptr` cannot be saved in a vector because of its destructive copy and assignment. I can understand it somehow and one example I can think of is something like `auto_ptr ap = vec[0]` will surprise me. But what if I use it cautiously and do not do this, can I store `auto_ptr` in a vector? Is there any deeper reason why I cannot store? Maybe the implementation of vector internally needs this assumption that elements need to be copy constructable?

Thanks.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated and very hard to use correctly. Try switching to `unique_ptr`, it will make things much easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

When a vector is resized, its elements are copied to a new backing array, this is where the copy constructor is used. If you have a sufficiently new compiler, look into using std::unique_ptr instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because vector has to store an already constructed object inside its storage. So, it has to copy the object into its own storage.

Also vector to assure `scope-safety`, it has to copy/move the object passed.

See the documentation of push_back

```
std::vector::push_back
void push_back( const T& value );   (1)
void push_back( T&& value );    (2)     (since C++11)
```

> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
>
> 2) value is moved into the new element.
>
> Parameters
>
> value     -   the value of the element to append
>
> Type requirements
>
> - T must meet the requirements of `CopyInsertable` in order to use overload
> - T must meet the requirements of `MoveInsertable` in order to use overload

And `CopyInsertable` id defined as

> Specifies that an instance of the type can be copy-constructed in-place, in  uninitialized storage.